# Query for days since last value change

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following data that includes any change to coupon program (Rate & Status)

| timestamp | account_ID | active | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1675894331538 | 1234 | true | 5 |
| 1675386736152 | 1234 | false | 0 |
| 1674778434298 | 1234 | true | 7 |
| 1673500367524 | 1234 | true | 5 |
| 1673309563251 | 1234 | true | 8 |

I am trying to determine how to best write a query to have the output look like this:

| account_ID | days_since_status_change | days_since_rate_change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2 | 4 |

I've been looking into using row_number and partitioning by account_id over timestamp DESC, but I can't wrap my head around how to narrow it down to two specific events and then counting the days since that event happened.

If you can make suggestions, this n00b would really appreciate the help!

I'm using BigQuery if that helps too.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider below query.

```sql
SELECT account_ID,
       COUNTIF(active_chage) OVER w1 AS days_since_status_change,
       COUNTIF(rate_change) OVER w1 AS days_since_rate_change
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
           active <> LAG(active) OVER w0 AS active_chage,
           rate <> LAG(rate) OVER w0 AS rate_change
      FROM sample_table
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY account_ID ORDER BY timestamp)
  ) QUALIFY timestamp = MAX(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY account_ID)  
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY account_ID ORDER BY timestamp);
```

**Query results**

[image]